# Check checkbox by default Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form_for Horse.new

Then I have a line

```
 <%= f.check_box :is_public, {checked: true, class: "positionRelative marginTopM3"} %>
```

Which creates the following HTML

```
 <input checked="checked" class="positionRelative marginTopM3" id="horse_is_public" name="horse[is_public]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Though the checkbox is not checked. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried Horse.new(is_public: true) but to no avail.

I am really lost here been googling around for an hour now without success. Will appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the browser, your HTML says `checked="checked"` which is what rails will generate if your `is_public` set to `true` and that's what it should be. try to clean up your browser cache (try different browser as well)

Comment: Cleared cache and saved form data for the past day in tried also in Firefox (been in Chrome now). Still the same hm.

Comment: it also might happen if you have some malformed HTML content on the page. make sure you have DOCTYPE and everything set correctly. Generally the rails part is correct `checked="checked"` should work fine

Comment: You're correct some other .js was unchecking it at load time. Thank you!